# Does clicking on OK in the "flag for moderator" window with an empty input text field raise any flag?

Tags: support, chat, chat-flags

Does clicking on OK in the "flag for moderator" window with an empty input text field raise any flag?

[image: the OK button on the "flag for moderator" pop-up]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**

While clicking the OK button dismisses the pop-up, it does not raise any flag:

1. No "Thanks, we'll take a look at it." message
2. No [notification badge for mod-flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZykW.png) shown

<sup>(tested on my private mod-only sandbox chat room)</sup>