# Keep the "flag for moderator" window opened when the user clicks on OK with an empty input text field and/or have some error/warning message

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-flags

Since [clicking on OK in the “flag for moderator” window with an empty input text field doesn't raise any flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348680/178179), it'd be more user-friendly to keep the "flag for moderator" window opened after the user clicks on OK with an empty input text field  and/or have some error/warning message indicating that the input text field must be non-empty for the flag to be raised.

Comment: Of course, but if we don't implement this feature then we could continue to trick evil users into thinking that they're spamming the moderator queue with empty flags which would prevent them from doing any *real* abuse... at least for a little while. But on the other hand I still agree that we should be notified for sending empty flags that don't get sent since we already have a bunch of other security measures for abuse.

Comment: @mindstormsboi if spam flag is an issue just add some flag raising threshold, which I believe is already in place.